# vector is faster than list in list fastest operations

Tags: algorithm, performance, list, c++11, vector

I wrote a simply A* algorithm for my game:

Navigation.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class Field;

//Comparer using by set to allow priority
struct FieldComparer
{
    bool operator()(const Field *, const Field *) const;
};

using FieldSet = set<Field*, FieldComparer>;
using FieldContainer = vector<Field*>; ///////////////////////////faster than list ?!

//Contains info about field, buildings builded on it and type of terrain
class Field
{
private:
    sf::Vector2i mapPosition{ 0, 0 };

    unsigned hCost{ 0 }; //to goal
    unsigned gCost{ 0 }; //to start

    Field *  parent;

    bool     isWalkable { true };
    bool     isPathPart { false };
public:
    void SetParent(Field&);
    Field * GetParent() const;

    unsigned GetFCost() const; //sum of hCost and gCost
    unsigned GetHCost() const;
    unsigned GetGCost() const;

    bool     IsWalkable() const;
    bool     IsPathPart() const;

    void SetHCost(unsigned);
    void SetGCost(unsigned);

    void SetWalkable(bool);
    void SetAsPartOfPath(bool);

    sf::Vector2i GetMapPosition() const;

    //compares positions
    bool operator == (const Field& other);

    Field(sf::Vector2i mapPosition, bool isWalkable) 
        : mapPosition(mapPosition), isWalkable(isWalkable) {}
};

//Contains fields and describes them
class Map
{
private:
    sf::Vector2u mapSize;
    Field *** fields; //two dimensional array of fields gives the fastest access
public:

    sf::Vector2u GetMapSize() const;
    Field *** GetFields();

    Map(sf::Vector2u);
    Map() {}
};

//Searching patch after giving a specified map
class PathFinder
{
private:
    //Calculate score between two fields
    unsigned CalcScore(Field&, Field&) const;

    //Get neighbours of field in specified map
    FieldContainer GetNeighbours(Field&, Map&) const;
public:

    //Find path that have the lowest cost, from a to b in map
    FieldContainer FindPath(Map&, Field&, Field&);

    //Reconstruct path using pointers to parent
    FieldContainer ReconstructPath(Field*, Field*) const;
};
```

Navigation.cpp

```
#include "Navigation.hpp"

#pragma region Field

    void Field::SetParent(Field & parent) { this->parent = &parent; }
    Field * Field::GetParent() const { return parent; }

    unsigned Field::GetFCost() const { return hCost + gCost; }
    unsigned Field::GetHCost() const { return hCost; }
    unsigned Field::GetGCost() const { return gCost; }

    bool Field::IsWalkable()   const { return isWalkable; }
    bool Field::IsPathPart()   const { return isPathPart; }

    void Field::SetHCost(unsigned value) { hCost = value; }
    void Field::SetGCost(unsigned value) { gCost = value; }

    void Field::SetWalkable(bool isWalkable)     { this->isWalkable = isWalkable; }
    void Field::SetAsPartOfPath(bool isPathPart) { this->isPathPart = isPathPart; }

    sf::Vector2i Field::GetMapPosition() const { return mapPosition; }
    bool Field::operator == (const Field& other)
    {
        return this->mapPosition == other.GetMapPosition();
    }

#pragma endregion Field

#pragma region Map

    sf::Vector2u Map::GetMapSize() const { return mapSize; }
    Field *** Map::GetFields() { return fields; }
    Map::Map(sf::Vector2u mapSize) : mapSize(mapSize)
    {
        //initialize map
        fields = new Field**[mapSize.x];

        //initialize all fields
        for (unsigned x = 0; x < mapSize.x; x++)
        {
            fields[x] = new Field*[mapSize.y];

            for (unsigned y = 0; y < mapSize.y; y++)
            {
                fields[x][y] = new Field({static_cast<int>(x), static_cast<int>(y)}, 
                { 
                    (!(y == 3 && x >= 1) || (x == 5 && y < 4))              
                });
            }
        }
    }

#pragma endregion Map

#pragma region PathFinder

    bool FieldComparer::operator()(const Field * l, const Field * r) const
    {
        return l->GetFCost() <  r->GetFCost() ||   //another field has smaller fcost
               l->GetFCost() == r->GetFCost() &&   //or fcost equals, and checked field is nearer to goal than current field
               l->GetHCost() <  r->GetHCost();

    }

    unsigned PathFinder::CalcScore(Field & a, Field & b) const
    {
        sf::Vector2u dst
        {
            static_cast<unsigned>(abs(b.GetMapPosition().x - a.GetMapPosition().x)),
            static_cast<unsigned>(abs(b.GetMapPosition().y - a.GetMapPosition().y))
        };

        return (dst.x > dst.y ? 14 * dst.y + 10 * (dst.x - dst.y) :
                                14 * dst.x + 10 * (dst.y - dst.x));
    }

    FieldContainer PathFinder::GetNeighbours(Field & f, Map & m) const
    {
        FieldContainer neighbours{};

        //cout << "checking neighbours for field: { " << f.GetMapPosition().x << ", " << f.GetMapPosition().y << " }\n";
        for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
        {
            for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
            {
                int xPos = f.GetMapPosition().x + x;
                int yPos = f.GetMapPosition().y + y;

                if (x == 0 && y == 0) //dont check the same field
                    continue;

                //check that field is in the map
                bool isInTheMap = (xPos >= 0 && yPos >= 0 && xPos < m.GetMapSize().x && yPos < m.GetMapSize().y);

                if (isInTheMap)
                {
                    neighbours.push_back(m.GetFields()[xPos][yPos]);
                }
            }
        }

        return neighbours;
    }

    FieldContainer PathFinder::FindPath(Map& map, Field& a, Field& b)
    {
        FieldSet open = {};   //not expanded fields
        FieldSet closed = {}; //expanded fields

        a.SetHCost(CalcScore(a, b)); //calculate h cost for start field, gcost equals 0
        open.insert(&a);             //add start field to open vector

        while (!open.empty()) //while we have unexpanded fields in open set
        {
            Field * current = *open.begin(); //set current field

            //if current checked field is our goal field
            if (*current == b)
            {
                return
                    ReconstructPath(&a, current); //return reversed path
            }

            closed.insert(current); //end of checking current field, add it to closed vector...
            open.erase(open.find(current)); //set solution

            //get neighbours of current field
            for (auto f : GetNeighbours(*current, map))
            {
                //continue if f is unavailable
                if (closed.find(f) != closed.end() || !f->IsWalkable())
                {
                    continue;
                }

                //calculate tentative g cost, based on current cost and direction changed
                unsigned tentativeGCost = current->GetGCost() + (current->GetMapPosition().x != f->GetMapPosition().x && current->GetMapPosition().y != f->GetMapPosition().y ? 14 : 10);

                bool fieldIsNotInOpenSet = open.find(f) == open.end();
                if (tentativeGCost < f->GetGCost() || fieldIsNotInOpenSet)
                {
                    f->SetGCost(tentativeGCost);
                    f->SetHCost(CalcScore(*f, b));
                    f->SetParent(*current);

                    if (fieldIsNotInOpenSet)
                    {
                        open.insert(f);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return {}; //no path anaviable
    }

    FieldContainer PathFinder::ReconstructPath(Field * a, Field * current) const
    {
        FieldContainer totalPath { current };

        while (!(current == a))
        {
            totalPath.push_back(current);
            current->SetAsPartOfPath(true);
            current = current->GetParent();
        }

        std::reverse(totalPath.begin(), totalPath.end()); //reverse the path
        return totalPath;
    }

#pragma endregion PathFinder
```

...and I am wondering why when I use std::list instead of std::vector, time of execute path finding algorithm equals or is bigger than in std::vector, because there are only adding operations for FieldContainer.

I was checking execution times 10 times in a loop using std::chrono high resolution timer:

```
#include "MapDrawer.h"
#include <iostream>

#include "Navigation.hpp"
//clock
#include <chrono>

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock ChronoClock;

using namespace sf;

bool pathFound = false;

FieldContainer path;
Map gameMap;

const sf::Vector2f mapSize { 300, 300 };

void Test()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        gameMap = { static_cast<sf::Vector2u>(mapSize) };
        PathFinder pathFinder{};

        auto t1 = ChronoClock::now();

        path = pathFinder.FindPath(gameMap, *gameMap.GetFields()[0][0], *gameMap.GetFields()[(int)(mapSize.x - 1)][(int)(mapSize.y - 1)]);

        auto t2 = ChronoClock::now();

        std::cout << "Delta: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " milliseconds\n";
    }
}


void MapDrawer::draw(RenderTarget &target, RenderStates states) const
{
    if (!pathFound)
    {
        Test();
        pathFound = true;
    }
    ////////////////
}
```

Results in ms (DEBUG)

```
map size        container       time (average)
  50x50           list               13,8
  50x50          vector              12,4
 150x150          list               54,0
 150x150         vector              41,9
 300x300          list              109,9
 300x300         vector             100,8
```

Result in ms (RELEASE)

```
map size        container       time (average)
 500x500          list               9,3
 500x500         vector              7,4
1500x1500         list              23,9
1500x1500        vector             23,7
```

So it looks like the vector is more fast than list, but why, since list should be faster in adding operations?

Btw. is that algorithm fast? If no, then what I could change to increase the speed?

Thanks.

Comment: Helpful reading: https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists . The "My 2012 “Going Native” Keynote." linked from the linked page goes into some pretty good-to-know details.

Comment: Of course a list is slower: it has to store each element in non-contiguous memory. You should use a `deque`, or `vector` if possible.

Comment: Vectors will have performance issues when trying to expand, otherwise access is O[1].  A list will have to search for the end of the list (unless it has a tail pointer), allocate a new node, then append the new node to the list.

Comment: Optimized release build or not?

Comment: @RetiredNinja ohh I forgot about release mode, btw. WOW 100ms -> 4ms I didn't know that release mode is so powerful...

Answer (score 3):

There *are* cases where a list will be faster than a vector.

The obvious is inserting a lot of items at the beginning of the collection:

```
template <class T>
void build(T &t, int max) {
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        t.insert(t.begin(), i);
}
```

A quick test shows that inserting 100000 ints like this takes hundreds of milliseconds for `vector` and 5 ms for a `list` (though for this case, a deque is the obvious choice--at about half a microsecond, it's *much* faster than either vector or list).

For list to make sense, you need to insert somewhere in the middle of a list that's already fairly large--and (the important part) you need to make *many* insertions at that same point, so you don't spend a lot of time traversing the list to find where to do your insertions. For example, if we do like this:

```
template <class T>
void build2(T &t, int max) {
    max = max / 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        t.insert(t.begin(), i);

    auto pos = t.begin();

    for (int i = -max; i < 0; i++)
        t.insert(t.begin(), i);

    // Now `pos` refers to the middle of the collection, insert some there:    
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        t.insert(pos, i);
}
```

(Minor aside: for `deque` or `vector` the code has to be slightly different--since `pos` could be invalidated by any of the subsequent insertions, the third loop for them looks like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    t.insert(t.begin() + max, i);
```

So anyway, with this we finally have contest where `list` wins over either `vector` or `deque`. For this task I get times of (note: this isn't with the same number of objects, so the times aren't comparable to the preceding):

```
  List: 500 us
 Deque: 3500 us
Vector: 6500 us
```

Of course, this isn't the final (or only) word on the subject either--a great deal also depends on things like how large of items you're dealing with, since large items are (at least usually) fairly slow to copy.

Interesting aside: `vector` always expands at the end, but `deque` can expand at either the end or the beginning, so even though it's not ideal, it's still noticeably faster for this task than a `vector`.

Oh, one other point: the timing can vary somewhat with the compiler/library as well. The immediately preceding times were for gcc. With VC++, list is about the same, vector is about twice as fast, and deque is *much* slower:

```
  List: 526 us
 Deque: 37478 us
Vector: 3657 us
```

(Executed on the same system as the preceding).

Comment: The implementation of `std::deque` in MSVC's libstdcpp [sucks balls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16252347/1794345) so that's not such a surprise :)

Comment: @Rerito: Unfortunately, he failed to explain the problem in what I'd consider sufficient detail (though I'll admit, I didn't try to explain it at all in this answer either--but mostly because he hadn't asked about deque in the first place).